# The range of values of $a$ such that...

Tags: analytic-geometry, triangles, self-learning, conic-sections, tangent-line

**Question**

*The range of values of 'a' for which the common tangent to the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and the parabola $y^2=4x$ and their chord of contact can form an equilateral triangle is_______.*

I know that it is not appreciated to ask here without uploading any work, but, I am not able to think any thing on this. I am not able to approach this question. Any hints and suggestions are welcome.

Thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: Start by making a sketch. Calculate the intersection points

Comment: @Andrei Calculated the intersection points. $x=\frac{-a^2}{b^2} + a\sqrt{4a^2+1}$. Two intersection points, one lies in first quadrant and another in fourth quadrant.

Comment: You may use that the slope of the tangent will be the same if you get it from the parabola or the ellipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ be the points of contact of the common tangent on the ellipse and parabola respectively, above the $x$ axis. Note that since the curves are symmetric with respect to the $x$ axis, the other two points of contact below the $x$ axis are given by $(x_1,-y_1),(x_2,-y_2)$. Again, because of symmetry, the $x$ axis is the angle bisector of the common tangents. Since we require the angle between the tangents to be $60\deg$, the tangents are inclined at $30\deg$ above and below the $x$ axis, their slopes given by $\tan(\pm30\deg)=\pm1/\sqrt3$.

Differentiate the equation of the parabola with respect to $x$ and set $y'=1/\sqrt3$,

$\displaystyle y^2=4x\implies yy'=2\implies y_2=2\sqrt3, x_2=3$

The equation of the common tangent is $\displaystyle\frac{y-2\sqrt3}{x-3}=\frac1{\sqrt3}$ and its intercepts on the axes are $(-3,\sqrt3)$.

The common tangent should intersect the ellipse only once.

$\implies |b|< \sqrt3, |a|<3$
[image: Figure]

Comment: Please Explain how did you get this - "Since we require the angle between the tangents to be $60\deg$, the tangents are inclined at $30\deg$ above and below the $x$ axis, their slopes given by $\tan(\pm30\deg)=\pm1/\sqrt3$."

Comment: Since they form an equilateral triangle, the angle between the common tangents is $60\deg$. By symmetry, the common tangents are reflections of each other about the $x$ axis. I'm updating the image

Comment: Understood your point. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: You are welcome